# Clear text value of textbox asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry if I did not explain well.

Create a website with ASP.NET C #, I have a page that I use to insert data into SQL Server, which has several TextBox controls where necessary to insert data is entered.

Everything works fine for the insertion of data in SQL, data are sent to a class to insert using a stored procedure to delete the content end of the TextBox controls using "TextBox.Text = string.Empty". Works excellent everything is erased. Check the Debug Mode and if you delete the contents of the TextBox controls.

But if you refresh the page the method that sends the data to the class to insert runs automatically; validations have to keep out if the controls are empty but overlooked. Reviewing the Debug Mode to see it again to refresh using the same data that was just deleted controls.

Why does that happen and how do I fix it.

Comment: FYI, "idk" is not a word.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand - I read it a few times and I have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: Hard to say where the error is if you don't show any code. Btw, you can clear the textboxes with `TextBox.Clear();`

Comment: instead of paste some code

Comment: Sorry if dont explain well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different things happen in different situations when you refresh the page.

If the page was created as a response to a post/postback, then the posted data will be sent to the server again to request the page. That means that the server code will react the same as when the page was first created, including for example saving the form data or getting new data from the database.

If you want to prevent the form data to be resent on a refresh, you can do a `Response.Redirect` when the server reacts to a form submission. That will make the browser do a `GET` request to fetch the page, so there will be no form data to repost.

Different browsers handle form data in a request slightly differently. Most browsers remember form data to some extent, so when you refresh the page some of the form data may be remembered by the browser, and will replace the values that the server put in the form fields.

If you refresh the page for testing, you can use `ctrl+F5` to tell the browser to make a "clean refresh", i.e. get everything from the server instead of using data from the cache, and don't fill the form with saved data.

Comment: Thanks, one for help me the redirect works, and two for understand me.